# Is Event.wait necessary here?

Tags: python, multithreading

When I read some code,I think the usage of Event is not necessary,is it right?

```
# start server
while True:
    # accept a request here
    queue.put(info)
    event.set() # notify all the threads?
    # pass queue and event here to a Thread constructor
```

other place there are more than 10 threads running,

```
# inside a Thread class
def __init__(self, queue, event):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.queue, self.event = queue, event

def run(self):
    while True:
        self.event.wait() # <- block here, I think this can be removed
        info = self.queue.get() # <- block here again, only one thread can get job to do?
        # do something
        self.queue.task_done()
        self.event.clear() #
```

Comment: In the small snippets of code that you posted, it does indeed seem that `event` is unnecessary. Furthermore, it seems as if event is global, which is probably not a good idea either, if it is to be used, event should be stored as an instance variable of the thread class.

Comment: They are not global,I have updated the snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as `queue` is actually `Queue.Queue` (or another collection with its own blocking mechanic), the event object is not required in the code you posted. <del>I'd even say that it's used incorrectly. There is a racing condition when the server calls `event.set()` and a thread is just done with its current task, calling `event.clear()`. This leaves all threads waiting on the event, even though there's an item in the queue.</del>

Edit: Bollocks, didn't think that one through. `event.set()` wakes up all threads that are hanging on `event.wait()`, causing them to continue waiting at `queue.get()`. One thread will fetch the item and process it. So, no racing condition. Just redundancy.

Comment: IOW `Queue.Queue` is thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

The Queue module has implemented multi-producer, multi-consumer queues, which is thread-safe.So you can remove event object.The queue.get() will block there and wait something to happen that you expected.